# Android: Get Chip icon click event

Tags: android, android-chips, material-components-android

I use material component Chip. In chip we can get close icon click and whole chip click event. But Not able to find chip icon click.

```
<com.google.android.material.chip.Chip"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
android:textColor="@color/chip_text_color"
app:checkedIconEnabled="false"
app:chipBackgroundColor="@color/chip_background"
app:chipIcon="@drawable/ic_pencil_edit_button"
app:chipIconSize="15dp"
app:chipIconTint="@color/chip_text_color"
app:chipStrokeColor="@color/colorPrimary"
app:chipStrokeWidth="1dp"
app:closeIconTint="@color/colorYellow"
app:iconStartPadding="@dimen/spacing_tiny" />
```

[image: Chip image]

Comment: chip.setOnCloseIconClickListener { chipGroup.removeView(chip as View) } is this one you want

Comment: @AravindV I want click of edit icon. The one with square red color marked.

Comment: Have you tried with _ChipDrawable_ with _ImageSpan_?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your Chip view has id **chip**:

```
findViewById<Chip>(R.id.chip).setOnTouchListener { v, event ->
    if (v is Chip) {
        if (event.x <= v.totalPaddingLeft) {
            //HANDLE CLICK TO THE ICON
        }
        return@setOnTouchListener true
    }
    return@setOnTouchListener false
}
```

Comment: But while useing this touch method than setOnCloseIcon method is not called and also proper ripple effect is not coming.

Comment: Did you try return false inside if block?